# can fastcgi_index have two values on nginx virtual.conf file?

Tags: nginx

I am wondering if you can have more than one 'fastcgi_index' in nginx virtual config file... If you view my virtual.conf below you will see I put **home.php** next to 'index.php' My home.php is more or less my sites index.php. My site is running ok (if it was running better I wouldn't be looking to see if any tweaks can be made) with index.php as the 'fastcgi_index' but I am not even sure why index.php was used (other than it is most likely the default setting for 'fastcgi_index') since my site uses home.php rather than index.php. So my question is... will my site run better if I replace my current 'fastcgi_index' (index.php) to home.php. Or can I put both in 'fastcgi_index' as noted below?

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    root           /home/xx/usr/share/nginx/html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php **home.php;**
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    include        fastcgi.conf;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, [`fastcgi_index`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFastcgiModule#fastcgi_index) can only take a single filename. This is because nginx doesn't search for the specified filename, it simply appends the string which you provide to the URL if it ends with a slash and hands it off to the FastCGI service. FastCGI paths don't have to exist as files on the filesystem, and so nginx cannot verify their existence.

Comment: thanks, so do you recommend I use index.php or home.php?

Comment: @Andrew `index.php` is more common, but it doesn't really matter. If you already use `home.php` then just go with that.

Comment: It doesn't actually matter which one you use.  Because of the location match, the url is already guaranteed to end with ".php" so fastcgi_index won't ever come into play.